# How to run Spek tests from command line?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have an android gradle project with JUnit tests and I've added a Spek test. It's working when I run it from the IDE, but `./gradlew testDebugUnitTest` does not include the Spek test, it only runs the JUnit tests.
Is there a way to run Spek tests with gradle or any other way from command line?

Comment: Could you post your gradle script (or at least the relevant parts)? Also, maybe this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/spek/issues/104) may help you.